# Changing a recursive function contract without completely reimplementing the function?

Tags: binding, clojure

I would like to change the contract of the following Quicksort implementation to return a count of the number of recursive calls needed to perform the sort operation.

Source: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#Clojure

```
(defn qsort [[pivot & xs]]
  (when pivot
    (let [smaller #(< % pivot)]
      (lazy-cat (qsort (filter smaller xs))
                [pivot]
        (qsort (remove smaller xs))))))
```

What I'd like to do is implement a `counted-qsort` that internally uses the above qsort implementation.

I'm looking for an example of how to do this.  I suspect `(bind ...)` may be involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I played around with this question for a little while, and here is what I came up with:

```
(defn counted-qsort [coll]
  (let [count (atom 0) qs qsort]
    (with-redefs [qsort (fn [coll]
                          (swap! count inc)
                          (prn coll)
                          (qs coll))]
      (dorun (qsort coll)))
    (deref count)))
```

This function temporarily redefines `qsort` so that it can manage an atom that holds a count for the number of times `qsort` is ultimately called. The `qs` in the let binding allows the original `qsort` function to be referenced in the redefined version to avoid infinite recursion.

I used "count" instead of "depth" because I am not sure "depth" is the right term to use.  This function counts the number of times `qsort` is called, not how deep the "tree" really is.

I don't know if laziness can be preserved with this approach.

Example output with `prn` for debugging:

```
[1 2 3]
()
(2 3)
()
(3)
()
()
7 ;return value
```

I assumed Clojure 1.3 and that `qsort` was already defined in the same namespace.